# In AngularJS how to use datalist

Tags: html, angularjs, html-datalist

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="" ng-controller="cntryController">
    <input list="testList" type="" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" ng-change="LoadSessionData(SelectedDoctor)" />
    <datalist id="testList">
        <option value="Dr.Test1" ng-selected="selected"></option>
        <option value="Dr.Test2"></option>
        <option value="Dr.Test2"></option>
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Controller

```
function cntryController($scope) {
    $scope.LoadSessionData = function(val) {
        console.log(val);
    };
}
```

check this Link http://jsbin.com/jifibugeke/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Above  mention datalist sample code  and URL using angularjs, here my problem is what ever i am typing the text box, in controller add by added every words,in my requirement in datalist selected details only shows in controller,

Comment: Here is little info on Datalist and AngularJS:

http://htmlcssjavascript.com/javascript/easy-autocomplete-with-the-datalist-element-the-list-attribute-and-angularjss-ng-repeat-directive/

Answer (score 28):

HTML

```
<div ng-app="myapp1" ng-controller="cntryController">
    <input list="testList" type="" ng-model="SelectedDoctor" ng-change="LoadSessionData(SelectedDoctor)" />
    <datalist id="testList">
        <option ng-repeat="x1 in names" value="{{x1.drname}}">
    </datalist>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
<script>
    var app=angular.module('myapp1',[]);
    app.controller('cntryController',function ($scope) {
//data for ng-repeat
    $scope.names=[{'drname':'Dr.Test1'},{'drname':'Dr.Test2'},{'drname':'Dr.Test3'}]
    $scope.LoadSessionData = function(val) {
//console log
        console.log(val);
    }
});
</script>
```

Example on [JSbin](https://jsbin.com/lequyoceye/edit?html,js,console,output)

Comment: <datalist> is love!!! 10,000 times neater than all possible alternatives pre HTML5. Really great, thanks!!! And works in IE :O

Comment: it's good but you don't really need to pass SelectedDoctor since you have access to $scope.SelectedDoctor from $scope.LoadSessionData

Answer (score 1):

This is right way for angular:

```
<input list="Calle" type="text" ng-model="xCalle"  >
    <datalist name="Calle" id="Calle" >
        <option value="11 DE SEPTIEMBRE DE 1888">
        <option value="12 DE OCTUBRE">
    </datalist>
```

Watch type="text" and where the name, id and ng-model are placed.

That will work with angular without any javascript additional function.