# Get data attribute value from datalist angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-model

I am currently using a `<datalist>` for easy lookup. Each `<option>` in my datalist has a `data-sysid` attribute which acts as the actual value I need. Currently, I am using `ng-model` to set the `id` variable. However, by default, `ng-model` uses the `value` attribute. Is there any way to make `ng-model` use the value set in my `data-sysid` attribute instead of the value?

Here is what I currently have:

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('myController', function($scope) {
    $scope.id = "";
  });

angular.element(document).ready(() => {angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp']);});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-controller="myController">
  <input list="items" id="item-choice" name="item-choice"
               placeholder="Choose an item" ng-model="id" />

  <datalist id="items">
    <option value="Item1" data-sysid="xyz">
    <option value="Item2" data-sysid="abc">
    <option value="Item3" data-sysid="123">
  </datalist> 
  
  {{ id }}
  <!-- I would like this to display data-sysid value instead -->
</div>
```

My desired behaviour would be like so:

- if I was to select `"Item1"` the display (`id`) would be `xyz`
- if I was to select `"Item2"` the display (`id`) would be `abc`
- if I was to select `"Item3"` the display (`id`) would be `123`

Is there any way to achieve this using angularjs (preferably without jQuery)?

Comment: you can't use ng-model on datalist. There is already a same question on SO.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531889/in-angularjs-how-to-use-datalist

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In AngularJS how to use datalist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531889/in-angularjs-how-to-use-datalist)

Comment: Hi @JeremyJStarcher I have looked at the duplicate question. It seems to be about how to model the input values (both while the user is entering them and when selected) to a particular variable. My question is different as it is about how to get the value of the `data-*` attribute from the selected value, not how to model the `value` attribute.

Comment: Fair enough... i've re-opened the question.